Live Reload on Google Chrome
I started realizing that whenever I am saving my code, I have to reload the webpage to see the changes. Previously, when I  had saved the file in which the code was in - the browser would automatically reload and I can see the changes within a second. But for some reason, this is not working for me right now. I am using Google Chrome. Usually on the console it would say Live Reload Enabled but now it does not say that, so is there a way to enable it once again? PLEASE HELP ME!
NOTE: I HAVE NODE.JS
I tried resetting the settings but that did not work, I also tried to see if their were some settings of enabling live reload in Visual Studio Code. No settings like that.

A webpage livereload is not a nodejs thing. Is a library thing. Whatever thing you are developing MAY have a livereload utility (react using webpack, for example).
